# Finding the formula of sum $(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2+...(k+(n-1))^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know the sum of square of numbers which stars from $1$
but I don't know what the formula becomes when the first term is not $1$ as follow

$$(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2+...(k+(n-1))^2$$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}(k+r)^2 = (n-1)k^2+2k\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}r + \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}r^2$

Comment: add $1 + 2^2 + \cdots + k^2$ and subtract it. then try to see if you can find something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{i = k}^n i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i^2$$

$\text{Now substitute using the fact that }$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$$

Comment: I think that the second term becomes $\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^2$

Comment: @Reery The left hand side includes the sum of $k^2$. If we set the upper bound of the second series to $k$, we'd be excluding it.